# How can an invisible stalker be summoned?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, summoning

In the *Monster Manual* there's this lore:

> Invisible stalkers are creatures native to the Elemental Plane of Air. They sometimes serve wizards and sorcerers, who summon them to perform specific tasks.

But how about the rest of it? Can a PC summon one? Are there any rules that explain how to do it? I can't find anything in *5E* besides this.

Comment: @Marq (It looks like you're going through and changing *How to* question titles to proper questions. In all seriousness, I applaud your efforts. But—especially on older questions that've already been read a bunch of times—fixing *just* the title is fine only *if* the body of the question's already awesome; that is, see if there are other edits that can be made to improve the question, too. Don't waste a bump on a 2-year-question just for the title when the question's body can also be improved!)

Comment: Fair enough; I wasn't aware that bumps were something to worry about "wasting".

Comment: @Marq (It's not really the bump that's a big deal but the series of relatively minor edits. Appropriate Meta discussion is [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4997/8610). And, also, feel free to ignore me and keep on doin' your thing—I'm no moderator and policy on this *is* flexible. Finally, to alert a user that a comment's directed *at* that user, employ an `@` followed immediately by the user's name (no space between—like I did to start this one) in the comment somewhere—skip that though if the comment is directed at the question or answer's original author. Just a heads-up.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yep, I grok the @-notifications, just brainfarted on this one.

Comment: **Historical note:** Prior to third edition, most editions of D&D included an *invisible stalker* spell that would summon exactly what it said on the tin. Third edition introduced the consolidated planar binding spells that allowed a caster to summon almost any outsider.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The spell *Conjure Elemental*, cast as a 6th level spell, can summon an Invisible Stalker. It's available to Druids and Wizards at 9th level, but obviously they will have to wait until 11th level to cast it as a 6th level spell.

If you know the name of an Invisible Stalker, you could also summon it with *Gate*, a 9th level spell available to Clerics, Sorcerers and Wizards at 17th level.

Finally, *Planar Ally*, a 6th level spell available only to Clerics, can summon an Invisible Stalker if your otherworldly entity of choice deems it appropriate.

Note that neither *Gate* nor *Planar Ally* place any restrictions on the creature's action, and from the description of the Invisible Stalker it probably won't be too happy to help you. The combination of *Magic Circle* and *Planar Binding* can be used to **make** it serve you, though.

Outside of these options, it's important to remember that the Monster Manual is intended as a DM resource. The description of the Invisible Stalker is meant to provide you with potential story hooks. The sentence you're asking about could probably be rephrased as:

> An Invisible Stalker makes a great servant for a wizard or sorcerer NPC.
>
> (Not actually a quote.)

Comment: *Planar binding* can be used to extend the duration of the elemental's service.

Comment: @JoshClark Yeah, although you need *magic circle* to make it work. I thought about adding it in, but I wasn't sure if I was over-complicating the answer.

Comment: +1 Very nice answer. I wonder if you can expand on *magic items* that might summon an invisible stalker? (For example, I haven't seen *PotA* yet, but imagine that there might be elemental-themed items there capable of doing so.)

Comment: @Lexible Sadly, I already went through the DMG and PotA magic items, and there's none that help here.

Comment: Oh, but how awesome of you to have done so! :)))

Answer (score 6):

An Invisible Stalker can be summoned by casting *Conjure Elemental* using a 6th-level or higher spell slot.

*Planar Ally* also has the potential to summon one if the primordial being the PCs are trying to beseech decides to send one to help.